# Pandas dataframe groupby + apply + new column is slow

Tags: python, performance, pandas, group-by, apply

I have a Pandas Dataframe. I use a `groupBy` (on 1 column) + `apply` combination to add a new column to the dataframe. The apply calls a custom function with an argument. The complete call looks like this:

```
df = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: customFunction(x,'searchString'))
```

The custom function works as follows: based on an `if` `else` condition, the new column is either filled with `1` or `0`. Then the group is returned. A bit generalized, the custom function looks like this:

```
def customFunction(group,searchString):
    #print(group.iloc[[0]]['id'].values[0])
    if len(group[(group['name'] == searchString)) > 0:
        group['newColumn'] = 1
    else:
        group['newColumn'] = 0
    return group
```

My problem is that the script runs relatively long, even though I do not deal with really much data. These are the stats of my data:
The dataframe has 3130 rows and 49 columns. The groupBy generates 1499 separate groups.

If I output some debugging text in the `customFunction`, I observe that the actual iteration through each group is fairly quick, however at the very end it takes some more seconds (longer than the iterations themselves) until the `groupBy` is actually completed. I think this has something to do with reindexing or reassigning the new data from the new column.

My questions now are:

- Why does the `groupBy` + `apply` takes so long? Why does the part where the actual iteration is already finished, take so long?
- How can avoid this bottleneck? How can I improve my code (see above) to perform quicker?
- More generally: How can the pattern "*group by a specific column and then add a new column based on a condition*" be implemented most efficiently? Maybe one way is to create a separate data structure without the need for the return group. In a separate step, then, the newly computed data structure could be joined with the original dataframe. However, I am not quite sure if this really would perform better.

I have read return group should be avoided because it takes long, however I think in my case it is necessary, because I explicitly generate new data in my `customFunction` and this requires to return the data.

Comment: Please post sample data

Comment: Try aggregating the group before applying a function to it: `df.groupby('id').sum().apply(...)`

Comment: It takes long, because for each row you call your custom function. What are you trying to do? It should be possible to use a faster technique.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, no, in this case the custom function will be called once for each group (except the very first group - [Pandas makes one extra call for the first group (see __Notes__)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another more efficient (for this particular case) solution without `groupby`

```
>> searchString = 'searchString'
>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.random.choice(1000, 1000000)})
>> df['name'] = random_names  # 1000000 random strings of len 10
>> df.loc[np.random.choice(1000000, 1000, replace=False), 'name'] = searchString
>>
>> def solution_0(x):
>>   x = x.groupby('id').apply(lambda g: customFunction(g, searchString))
>>
>> def solution_1(x):
>>   x['newColumn'] = x.groupby('id')['name'].transform(lambda g: g.eq(searchString).any().astype(int))
>>
>> def solution_2(x):
>>   x['newColumn'] = 0
>>   x.loc[x['id'].isin(x.loc[x['name'] == searchString, 'id']), 'newColumn'] = 1
>> 
>> %timeit solution_0(df)
3.4 s ± 125 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
>> %timeit solution_1(df)
1.47 s ± 56.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
>> %timeit solution_2(df)
129 ms ± 4.33 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: wow. not really readable, but also (with my data) `solution_2` is 3 times faster than `solution_1`.

Answer (score 2):

`df.groupby(...).apply(...)` is not fully vectorized, as under the hood it's a `for .. loop` which will apply specified function to each group (in your case it'll be executed 1499+1 times).

[See **Notes** in the docs describing why Pandas apply will call func twice for the first group](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

> In the current implementation apply calls func twice on the first
>   group to decide whether it can take a fast or slow code path. This can
>   lead to unexpected behavior if func has side-effects, as they will
>   take effect twice for the first group.

It is recommended to look for a solution using vectorized functions first and if it's not possible to use `.apply()` as a last resort.

IIUC you can use the following vectorized approach:

```
In [43]: df
Out[43]:
   id name
0   1  aaa
1   1  bbb
2   1  aaa
3   2  ccc
4   2  bbb
5   2  ccc
6   3  aaa

In [44]: searchString = 'aaa'

In [45]: df['newColumn'] = df.groupby('id')['name'] \
                             .transform(lambda x: x.eq(searchString).any().astype(int))

In [46]: df
Out[46]:
   id name  newColumn
0   1  aaa          1
1   1  bbb          1
2   1  aaa          1
3   2  ccc          0
4   2  bbb          0
5   2  ccc          0
6   3  aaa          1
```

**Timing** for 70.000 rows DF:

```
In [56]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [57]: df.shape
Out[57]: (70000, 2)

In [58]: %timeit df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: customFunction(x,searchString))
10 loops, best of 3: 92.4 ms per loop

In [59]: %timeit df.groupby('id')['name'].transform(lambda x: x.eq(searchString).any().astype(int))
10 loops, best of 3: 53.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: thanks for this solution. just another related question: `transform` is not a `for ... loop` under the hood?

Comment: @beta, it's difficult to say. One would have to check to source code... I've added a timing

Comment: thanks. i am in a hurry right now. i will read your answer in detail later and then accept as answer (and then delete this comment). thanks!